# How to email error msg in catch

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the code below which I now need to figure out how to not only display but also email it all to my email, this way should any user encounter a error we get to see exactly what is it.

```
Catch ex As Exception
      lblInformation.Text = ("<h4>Unable to save data in database</h4>" + vbNewLine + "The error was '" + ex.Message + "'" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "The SQL Command which falied was:" + vbNewLine + "<strong>" + mySQL + "</strong>" + vbNewLine + "Please contact the Service Desk to report this error.").Replace(vbNewLine, "<br />" + vbNewLine)
      booInsertedRecord = False
Finally
      myConnection.Close()
End Try
```

I Tried inserting

```
SmtpMail.Send(objEMail)
```

in a new line above "booInsertedRecord = False" and then creating a new "Dim objEMail New MailMessage()" but then realised that won't work because it's msg is defined in the catch so not to sure what steps next to take.

It's been a while since I used VB and I didn't need to use anything like this then so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit - @tzup ToString() shows

```
[The error was 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ASP.bulletinform_aspx.Upload_Click(Object source, EventArgs e) in E:\Bulletin\Bulletin\Bulletin\BulletinForm.aspx:line 415']
```

would of put this in a comment if I had space, line 415 is `myUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @DavidePiras why did you remove the VS08 tag? it is a VS08 project to which I'm hoping not to have to upscale so isn't including that tag relevant?

Comment: No, because the question and answers we have here do not rely ( aka are not linked ) to any specific feature of VS 2008, if you were working with VS 2003 / 2005 or even 2010 all answers would have been the same. We use tags to highlight that the question is strictly related to a certain version of .NET Framework, VS or anything else and in case it was for another version the answer could have been different, which is not the case of this question :)

Comment: @DavidePiras Ah ok I wasn't sure if anything would be of issue so I added that on just to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the email object in the catch block, set the contents to the lblInformation.Text for example, and the send it.

That should work.

Create a static class for the email sending functionality, with a static function taking a string as a parameter for instance. Define this class in a util assembly, reference this assembly in your project and then call it whenever it is needed in your catch statements if you like.

Your class could be:
   EmailUtil.SendMail(string msg);

Then your SendMail function reads in some parameters from a config (the smtp server, login etc) and then sends the email over.

Other than that, log4net is pretty good at handling this scenario, once you configure it properly (not a very steep learning curve in my opinion)

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Here is an example of data validation with *TryParse*

```
string someTextVal = "3";
string someDateVal = "14.02.2011";

int i;
if (!int.TryParse(someTextVal, out i))
{
   throw new Exception("Error trying to convert value=" + someTextVal + " to an int");
}
// Now i holds a validated integer

DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(someDateVal, out dt))
{
   throw new Exception("Error trying to convert value=" + someDateVal + " to a datetime");
}
// Now dt holds a validated date
```

**NOTE** Datetime validations might require some teaks depending on how the input presents itself

**LATER EDIT** In case anybody needs to convert my C# code in VB (since the question was tagged with VB), here is a link to a online converter: [Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: This should work but we are reinventing the wheel every time... if it really has to be done without any logging library, I would then at least create a Logger class, call it passing the exception and send the email from there, just to avoid to copy paste too much code in all the catches of the application.

Comment: I had went ahead not expecting a fast response and tried to do just what you ended up saying and set "objEMail.Body = ("<h4>Unable to save data in database</h4>" + vbNewLine + "The error was '" + ex.Message + "'" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "The SQL Command which falied was:" + vbNewLine + "<strong>" + mySQL + "</strong>" + vbNewLine + "Please contact the Service Desk to report this error.").Replace(vbNewLine, "<br />" + vbNewLine)" my only issue now is if I'm able to get the error msg to be more precise as to which field it failed on ["The error was '" + ex.Message + ] is the section...

Comment: and it would show [The error was 'The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.]
I know the field this time which is causing the error is called [DateOfBirth] but there are a number of "datetime" fields so any idea how to refine the error msg some more to specify exactly which fields it is having a problem with?

Comment: Actually, instead of emailing the ex.Message, use ex.ToString(). That will give you a lot more info about the exception. Moreover, I would use a StringBuilder object to build the message (it performs better and the resulting code is more readable).

Comment: @tzup added in my question exactly what is now shown but otherwise how would I setup a StringBuilder object if you think that would tell me the exact field name(s) which caused an error?

Comment: StringBuilder won't help you in that matter. But it will make things easiear to read (and it advisable as it improves performance, but that's another topic). The strategy to use if you want to get the exact field which has thrown an exception is to have multiple try/catch blocks. Surround every conversion (like converting a string in a datetime) with try/catch. Thus errors are narrowed in code. Accumulate errors in a StringBuilder and at the end of the routine, send email with all errors, if any.

Comment: @tzup Problem is the converts r in a huge sql command[ Dim mySQL As String = "INSERT INTO [Blah].[dbo].[Bulletin](" _& " [DateOfBirth]," _& " VALUES(" _& " CONVERT(datetime,'" + DateOfBirth + "',103)," _& " getdate())" Dim myUpdate As New SqlCommand(mySQL, myConnection)] ofc with 45 other fields but this was the slimed down version, [Try EmployersName = txtEmployersName.Text Catch strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>Error:</strong> " & txtEmployersName.Text & vbCrLf) strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab) End Try] this is part of how else I tried to do it.

Comment: @tzup I tried to put all of the code like in the bottom of the above example into 1 big try/catch block with each new field having it's own try/catch block like the dateofbirth 1 u can see above and then I had in the big catch all the code to email and with the strEMessageBody.ToString() in the email body but that 1 wouldn't except the strEMes... in the body and 2 even just simple string of text in the email body it didn't send a email, so any ideas?

Comment: @tzup ok managed to get it to correctly to use the stringbuilder and add new lines into the email but right now I don't know what kind of logic to put into the try block for each field as validation.

Comment: @Myzifer it depends on the kind of validation that you want to perform. For converting text to numbers, you could use the TryParse methods exposed by, Decimal, Long, Int, etc.

Comment: @tzup well I have 2 kinds of converts (datetime and int) and otherwise everything else is either text or bool value from a checkbox/radiobutton, any help then with using the TryParse for those datatypes like a usual link or some code to guide me (I usually work in c# in mvc2 but have this project to fix because original devs did a rush job on it)? In the mean time I'll try and see what I can find out but unless I post again saying I've resolved it and with a link then assume I'm still stuck.

Comment: @tzup [ DateOfBirth = DateOfBirthYear.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthMonth.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthDay.SelectedItem.Value ] [ & " CONVERT(datetime,'" + DateOfBirth + "',103)," _ ] hoping I can use the DateOfBirth as what to validate

Comment: @ Myzifer Not sure I get the last part with the CONVERT. That is a t-sql function. Aren't you trying to validate a datetime before you save it in the DB?

Comment: the submit already has it that if the data isn't valid it won't write to the database but the problem is it doesn't display that information to the user or to me, what it does now is it display text at the top of the page upon submit if it fails it just says the data type of the field which failed and shows the whole sql insert command and all the data which was inputted, I've already set it up so I can write the exact field in the error msg but the problem is I need a way to validate it in the try/catch block and it seems ur edit is in c# and not vb right?

Comment: @tzup Try
                    
      Catch
           strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>Name Error:</strong> " & txtName.Text & vbCrLf)
           strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
       End Try    this is how I've presently setup the try catch but just struggling with getting the validation here on the try

Comment: Yes, C#, you can convert it to VB using this online tool: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @tzup from looking at the converter it seems these parts would be what matchs it,  Sub Upload_Click(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Page.IsValid) Then
            Dim Name As String
            Dim Other As Integer
            Dim DateOfBirth As String

with below this being

Name = txtName.Text
If cbOther.Checked = False Then
     Other = 0
Else
     Other = 1
End If
DateOfBirth = DateOfBirthYear.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthMonth.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthDay.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: @tzup I will as soon as I get it working if I get it working, simpliest and fastest way I can get it sorted is I can find some validation logic to put in a try block then I'd just have to uncomment out 100+ lines and add in the one extra line to the try block

Comment: @tzup got the date of birth one working now trying a couple more and if rest work out ok then yeh I'll mark ur answer correct

Comment: @Myzifer Good luck with the refactoring :)

Comment: @tzup tried [Dim sq As String
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(QualList, sq) Then
                    strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>txtQualList:</strong> " & txtQualList.Text & vbCrLf)
                    strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
                End If] but it doesn't like the the (QualList, sq) which if I take out the sq then it doesn't like it being used in the dim, in mean time I'm sorting all the other fields out which I can then I'll come bk to this

Comment: @tzup since it's hard to test [ Dim Name As String
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) Then
                strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>txtName:</strong> " & txtName.Text & vbCrLf)
                strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
            End If]  does this look like it will work correctly?

Comment: @tzup thing is tho the only way I can set it up like that is in [Sub Upload_Click(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Page.IsValid) Then] which leads me to believe that none of the string validation could be used since in the if (Page.IsValid) it would of already checked so I'll mark your answer as correct for now but otherwise I don't think this is the right place to put the code and in the other place where I put the date and int validation which I know is correct I can't use the same code since it's names conflict with the IsValid section named Dim's.

Comment: @tzup yep now it would just display all the string values in the email which shouldn't be the case since all the inputted string data should be correct and I've still got some things to figure out with the dropdowns to make sure they work correctly

Comment: @tzup do you know of any other way to validate a string pref with using a similar format as with a int or datetime?

Comment: I need more details, but first, how about you bring closure to this this question and we move on to another, as it seems to be the case.

Comment: @tzup http://stackoverflow.com/q/5016503/536217 there ya go made it as a separate question

Comment: Would of mentioned and done so yesterday but got assigned some other work while I wait for the user who encounter a problem to get bk to me but otherwise marking ur answer correct just would want for you to edit your answer to include that conversion link to the vb code to help any future readers and since this is a vb related question thx.

Answer (score 2):

Use a logger like log4net and setup an SmtpAppender.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/20210-Send-Exceptions-or-Error-Email-using-Log-Net.aspx

Comment: Cool, forgot about this functionality of log4net.

Answer (score 2):

Long long time ago Jeff Atwood created an User Friendly Exception Handler. I use it since :)
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/user-friendly-exception-handling.html

It allows to you e-mail the error, even including screenshot of the PC at the time of the exception.

Comment: well from reading about half the page I think this might just be to much of a complex or expansion solution for my problem, if I have to do any form of coding outside of the single page I have to work on then I'll prob need to upscale the project and that could cause hell and totally break it but looking into it to see if thats gona be the case or if it's a perfect solution.

Comment: from browsing the code it already looks like I'd have too change too much or affect to much of the system so looks like I need to focus on tzup's idea of using tryparse to check if each field is valid and if I can get that fully working then that will provide me exactly with with fields if any cause the error.

Comment: Well, this is "top handler" for any unhandled exceptions. So really you don't have to code anything. After the installation (adding reference and adjusting app/web.config) you just leave the exception unhandled in your code, and ExHandler will let you know about it, also display nice message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are logging systems to do this so you do not reinvent the wheel and you do not put any logic in the catch blocks you have in your code.

You can have a look at Log4Net and also Microsoft Logging Enterprise Libraries, I personally prefer and use Log4Net, in your catch block you will simply use something like Logger.LogError(exception) and depending on how you configure it in app.config you get everything logged in database and/or eventlog and/or via email and/or text file and much, much more.