# How to Validate a textbox+dropdowns in vb for a asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

[Previous question which links onto this and has any addition code ref should I forget to link any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4991357/536217), I have set it up to email me should someone submit this form and an error occur and right now should that occur for most integer or datetime fields if they fail to validate then it will show me which fields in the email failed and what was input into them.

Problem I'm having now is to validate the drop downs and the textboxs in a similar way to what I with integer and datetime fields so I can display those also in the email in case they error.

present integer and datetime validation

```
Catch ex As Exception
            lblInformation.Text = ("<h4>Unable to save data in database</h4>" + vbNewLine + "The error was '" + ex.Message + "'" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "The SQL Command which falied was:" + vbNewLine + "<strong>" + mySQL + "</strong>" + vbNewLine).Replace(vbNewLine, "<br />" + vbNewLine)

Dim dtb As DateTime
            If Not DateTime.TryParse(DateOfBirth, dtb) Then
                strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>Date Of Birth:</strong> " & DateOfBirthYear.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthMonth.SelectedItem.Value & "-" & DateOfBirthDay.SelectedItem.Value & vbCrLf)
                strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
            End If
Dim iao As Integer
            If Not Integer.TryParse(AnyOther, iao) Then
                strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>Any Other:</strong> " & rblAnyOther.Text & vbCrLf)
                strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
            End If
```

then below the final validation I have the Dim for the email setting but that I sorted out in the other question.

The problem is much earlier in the page I have

```
Sub Upload_Click(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (Page.IsValid) Then
        Dim Name As String
```

Which prevents me just using there names as shown above where I would instead call them something else but that doesn't work with strings so my main issue is having some bit of code to check if the strings are valid and for the dropdowns which would either work but always show the data in the email or would hiccup in the code,

```
Dim imd As Integer
            If Not Integer.TryParse(dept, imd) Then
                strEMessageBody.Append("<strong>Department:</strong> " & dept.Text & vbCrLf)
                strEMessageBody.Append("<br/>" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
            End If
```

below was how it had been setup to record the department
    Department = dept.SelectedItem.Value
            Department = Replace(Department, "'", "''")

Summary:- Need vb code to validate if strings and dropdowns are valid and the use of try/catch block is another possible solution but I wasn't able to figure out how to implement validation for that either.

Comment: It is emailing you if someone submits an invalid form?  That is just crazy... Let your code handle the validation and let them submit only when the page is valid...

Comment: @Matt that already is the case but one user is getting errors and they didn't record the error details so instead I've set it up that it will email me, the original dev would input everything from the form in 1 huge sql insert command and basically did a rush job with this so what I'm asking isn't crazy but a way to quickly diagnose what the issue is. But if you insist it's crazy then suggest an alternative to this?

Comment: Create a logging table called "tblLog" or something.  If your app or SQL hits an error write out the contents of the exception to the logging table.

Comment: when you say "strings and dropdowns are valid" what exactly do you mea? 1. Strings should not be null or empty? 2. Dropdowns should have a value selected? 3. Any other validations? (Please enumerate)

Comment: @tzup all of the above and in regards to point 3 well I can't think of any others right now but if there are other suitable validations you know of then those too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everybodies given up trying to find a solution then I'm just gona close this topic with this post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Log your values into your database.  Setup a logging table called "tblLog" or something else.  Record the value of ex.Message or possibly even InnerException (if it exists).

Comment: well I'd do so if the form actually got much input or wasn't so old but since in the 3 years it's been running it has only been used 88 times then this way is just as if not more effective since it will instantly alert me or whoever is in from my department and if I get this validation sorted it will identify exactly what the problem is from the start instead of waiting for who tried to use the form to ring and make sure they are entering in the correct info, so although your answer would be useful on my previous question it doesn't help with solving the current issue of validation to...

Comment: pinpoint exactly where there is a issue straight away, for example the original dev made the DOB as 3 drop downs which would mean they could input 31st of feb and that would ofc be wrong when it tried to convert that to datetime.

Comment: @Myzifer - If that is the case it sound like you really need to do some dev work on the page.  A form should be validated, but should never allow users enter data that is destined to fail.

Comment: in that regard if it was upto me I'd remake the whole form but it's not that simple since it's part of/connected to another form and a larger intranet db and everything else is not part of our responsibility/domain and we had only a couple things dumped on us to support after the original devs stopped doing so, anyway bk to the problem at hand, do you know how I can set up validation like which I've shown up in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Going hand in hand with [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155085/matt)'s answer, there is a tool that can help you with automatically logging errors to a DB.

It's called [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

**EDIT**

Here are 2 validations that you might want to use:

```
Dim s As String = "some user input in here" 
If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
    ' Watch out, string is null or it is an empty string
End If

Dim cb As New ComboBox()    
If cb.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    ' Watch out, combo has no item selected
End If
```

**NOTE** ComboBox is a WinForm control in this example, but the idea is the same for the ASP.NET counterpart

Comment: @tzup it would be nice to be able to add something like that to this but why use a helicopter to get to the local shops when a care will do, I already have it setup to email me if there's an error and the details regarding it, the only bit I'm missing it being able to validate strings and dropsdowns like I mentioned in my question since right now if anything else breaks then I'll be informed in the email but if those 2 things fail I won't be instantly pointed at them so any ideas on the validation?

Comment: @Myzifer I get your point, ELMAH is something to keep in mind for the next project. As for your validation question, I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: @tzup turns out the cause of this whole problem was that the original devs had tried to submit the DOB incorrectly and as such bam it screwed up everything so I simply fixed that and no more issues, in regards to the validation would [String] be replace with say [Name] which is my name input field and then in regards too Dim cb well it won't let me re-use the name of the field so how would I get it to be the same as it is for the string validation and the int+date validation in regards to Dim random as New ComboBox() If [Dept].SelectedItem(random) or something like this?

Comment: For strings, replace "s" with [Name]. For ComboBoxes, you need a referece to the actual object, then [comboBoxObj].SelectedItem is Nothing is the way to go.

Comment: @tzup I can't replace s with [Name] I already explained it won't let me because it conflicts with the use of Dim Name as String which is further up on the page hence me needing another way to identify each individual string. It has a blue underline for Name and it says (Variable 'Name' hides a variable in an enclosing block.) when I hover over it.

Comment: @tzup that gives me the warning [Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.]

Comment: Is [Name] defined as static field? If so, access it directly from its type.

Comment: @tzup [ Dim Name As String  |  Name = txtName.Text  |  Dim mySQL As String = "INSERT INTO [IntranetContent].[dbo].[blah](" _
                & " [Name]," _  |  & " VALUES(" _
                & " '" + Name + "'," _  ]  these are all the uses of this field cept for the asp coded textbox and I found that with how the dev coded it up left a big issue of if a user put ' in then it would break the insert ofc this only happened with the email address since a user would make a mistake inputing @

Comment: @tzup given up or just forgotten about this?

Comment: I lost track of this, you're asking too many things at once and it is hard to follow in comments. Perhaps asking other questions would be better.

Comment: @tzup it's the same question tho, I just had added more details in regards to the normal textbox valdation as u can see from the comment I posted on feb 28th

Comment: problem is this is how the previous devs setup dozens of pages so ideally I'd like to find a solution, preferably one where either on page it tells them they can't submit until they select a valid date.  Like on the latest form which has a checkbox next to the 3 date fields which if ticked there's no need for those fields to have input where as if not those fields are required which if in mvc I would have no issue sorting out but here it becomes a head ache.

Comment: I guess the only solution to this is figure out how to tie all the needed jquery into the page and then setup those values to have masks/validation rules and a datepicker